# Как правильно реализовать сериализацию объекта класса с полем, представляющим объект этого же класса?

Tags: java, сериализация, field

В голову пришла следующая ситуация:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private Foo foo1;
    ...
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом случае сериализация будет зациклена и будет выброшено какое-нибудь исключение? Этого можно избежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не будет зацикливания или исключения, сериализация пройдёт успешно.